# Is NumPy gradient works differently on images?

Tags: python, numpy, gradient

I try to implement gradient function in python. My function gave the same results on matrices as NumPy implementation but when I try with an image, the results are different. What NumPy do differently?

Numpy

[image: Numpy image]

My implementation

[image: My gradient image]

Source

```
  def own_gradientX(g):
  img=np.zeros((g.shape[0],g.shape[1]))
  for x in range(g.shape[0]):
    for y in range(g.shape[1]):
      if (x == 0):
        img[x][y] = g[x+1][y] - g[x][y]
      elif (x == g.shape[0]-1):
        img[x][y] = g[x][y] - g[x-1][y]
      else:
        img[x][y]=(g[x+1][y]-g[x-1][y])/2
  return img
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you failed to provide a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I can only guess you did something like this:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = Image.open('lena.jpg')
img = np.array(img)
```

where `img` is `uint8` datatype. Now if you directly compute gradient on the first channel of the image over the first axis:

```
def own_gradientX(g):
    img=np.zeros((g.shape[0],g.shape[1]))
    for x in range(g.shape[0]):
      for y in range(g.shape[1]):
        if (x == 0):
          img[x][y] = g[x+1][y] - g[x][y]
        elif (x == g.shape[0]-1):
          img[x][y] = g[x][y] - g[x-1][y]
        else:
          img[x][y]=(g[x+1][y]-g[x-1][y])/2
    return img


own_gradient = own_gradientX(img[...,0])
np_gradient_x, np_gradient_y = np.gradient(img[...,0])

np.allclose(own_gradient, np_gradient_x)
>>> False
```

Now if you cast to `float64` your image prior to computation:

```
img = np.array(img).astype(np.float64)
```

you will get the intended result:

```
np.allclose(own_gradient, np_gradient_x)
>>> True
```

[image: lena_gradient_check]

So there is nothing wrong with your implementation :)! You just need to carefully check the `dtype` of the input before any computations.